# Meters to Decimal degrees. High precision

Tags: java, gis, geospatial, jts

I'm working on a tool for GPS accuracy in Java.
I have a point with Lat Lon and need to build a circle with a certain radius.

There are many question like this, however in my case the radius is usually around 10 meters, +-5 meters, and I need it to be super precize.

For building a circle I use [JTS](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/javadoc/com/vividsolutions/jts/util/GeometricShapeFactory.html).

There is a a sample of code:

```
    import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.*;



    public static final int SRID = 4326;
    public static PrecisionModel precisionModel = new PrecisionModel(PrecisionModel.maximumPreciseValue);
    public static GeometryFactory geometryFactory = new GeometryFactory(precisionModel, SRID);

    public static Polygon createCircle(Point initialPoint, int coverArea){

    GeometricShapeFactory gsf = new GeometricShapeFactory(geometryFactory);
    ArrayList<Point> pointsOfIntersection = new ArrayList<>();

       // double radius = getRadius(point);
        double size = 0.0001 * coverArea/100;

        gsf.setSize(size);
        gsf.setNumPoints(50);
        gsf.setCentre(point.getCoordinate());
        Polygon circle = gsf.createCircle();

       return circle;
      }
```

Basically I have a center point with coordinates and will get a diameter based on that point (5 - 20 meters), after that I need to adjust that radius to `coverArea` coefficient (1 - 100 %) and set a size of a circle in decimal degrees.

For now I use 0.0001 value for testing purposes, which accroding to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees) gives around 10.247 meters.

So I need an easy and efficient formula to convert meters to decimal degrees.

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-coordconvert/

Comment: Can you post a little bit of code so we can see what you mean?

Comment: The earth's mean radius is 6371 km = 6.371e6 m.  You also need to know how to calculate distances in a spherical coordinate system from lat/lon values: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Answer (score 0):

The precision of your decimal degrees depends on how many decimal points you are using.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees

Simply use more to achieve what you're looking for (5-15 meters length).

Comment: Yes, I know it, but it also depends on latitude.... and all formulas that I found on the internet doesn't give accuracy within 1 meters.